# Do any databases allow multiple indexes on the same table to be created simultaneously?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I'm pretty sure this can't be done in Oracle, but I'd love to be proved wrong...

Say I have a huge table in with lots of columns and I want to create indexes on a dozen or so columns. Using Oracle, I'd fire off several sequential `create index` statements and go off and boil the kettle.

Each `create index` needs to scan through every row in the table to form the index.

i.e. 10 indexes = 10 full scans.

You'd think an obvious optimisation would be to scan the table once and index the 10 columns at the same time. Wouldn't you?

```
create indexes on mytable (
    ix_mytable_cola (cola),
    ix_mytable_colb (colb),
    ix_mytable_colc (colc)
);
```

So obvious that there must be a great reason why it's not there.

Any ideas?

I could fire off each `create index` simultaneously in separate sessions and hope the database buffer cache saved the day, but seems like a long shot.

**EDIT**

I didn't get a definitive answer so I asked the same question on Oracle-L:

http://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/Creating-multiple-indexes

General consensus was that it isn't available but would perhaps be a useful feature. Most useful response was from [David Aldridge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6742/david-aldridge) who suggested that if the create index statements were all kicked off at the same time then Oracle would 'do the right thing'.

Comment: I haven't seen any database that supports that. Maybe it's because they assumed that indexes would be created up front where this would not be a problem and not when the table has several GBs of data ;-)

Comment: I've never used Oracle so this'll likely be irrelevant. Anyway can't you create a new empty table with the same structure and required indexes and then fill it in from your original? This may or may not do what you're asking and it'll of course double the disk requirements temporarily. Still it could work :)

Comment: If I understood right you'd like to create indexes dynamically, but what is a reason you can't have indexes beforehand?

Comment: The suggestion from @noodl addresses your question.  Create an identical empty table, create all the indices, then copy the data from the old table into the new one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However, the pre-created indexes idea just doesn't work on data warehouse size tables. Loading data into a table with pre-existing indexes is a real performance killer (even if - as in Oracle's case - index creation can be delayed until data has been loaded). Typically in a data warehouse situation you would load data into a table with as few indexes as you can get away with and rebuild the indexes afterwards.

Comment: I see no problem in creating indexes in parallel. I have not tried it but why not? (Test would be to start create index in one sqlplus window and another create index in another). Also in Oracle you can improve index creation speed by using the parallel keyword and by using the nologging keyword. But yes it is a pity that indexes creation cannot make use of the indexes already there.

Comment: @Jürgen Hollfelder - yes, certainly indexes can be created in parallel, but creating each index requires a full scan of the table. I'm suggesting this could be optimised to a single full scan where each column to be indexed is sampled as each row is processed. This would only happen when creating indexes in parallel if the database buffer cache happened to be holding the relevant blocks required by each parallel session (and even then would still require the overhead of each session reading in from the buffer cache).

Comment: ... Imagine how you'd code creating 10 hash maps of the contents of 10 columns - would you loop through the table rows 10 times or would you loop through once and create 10 hash maps at once?

Comment: Can compound indexes help you? If your searches commonly involve multiple columns, you can create indexes several columns at once.

Comment: +1 This'd be a great feature.

Comment: @Barry Brown - compound indexes wouldn't help in the cases I'm thinking of, which would typically be multiple single-column bitmaps. The issue still remains for compound indexes... you may have multiple compound indexes designed to handle specific data access paths and each compound index create would require a full scan.

Comment: @Nick: I have a question now. What size of table are you talking about and what underlying hardware do you have? I am probably spoiled with what we have at my current client where we have tables with around 1 mio rows or less and a 256GB RAM 64 CPU machine. We do initial data migration from legacy systems but the machine is sized for future run-time. So I never asked myself how to increase the speed of building an index because all is pretty much "instant".

Comment: @Jürgen Hollfelder :) - fair to say our servers have neither 256GB of RAM nor 64 CPUs inside them, but for me it's the underlying IO which is always the blocker. Say you have a 100GB table and a real-world disk read-rate of 40MB/sec... that's 40 minutes to read in the table. So you improve things by getting faster disks, partitioning, and reading in parallel but there's still a chunk of data to get through. Say you can get it down to 5-10 minutes... if you have 10 indexes to create that's 50-100 minutes which is still an appreciable time of an overnight cube build, for example.

Comment: Remember, the biggest part of the indexing operation is *not* the table scan. Creating multiple indexes in parallel would only help if you were writing them all to separate disks. Maybe you can run the index creation commands from different connections and get them to run at the same time. Then the table scans might be able to make use of the disk cache.

Comment: @Nick: With this figures in mind, I agree that would be a very good feature. I don't think any DBMS does it but I am mostly experienced in Oracle.

Comment: @Gabe - why do you say the biggest part of the indexing operation is *not* the table scan? I find that it is in my cases. The CPU and database writer happily keep pace during index creation. I don't even think about which disks I'm writing too any longer - I'm given a chunk of SAN storage which is raided and striped across plenty of disks and only worry about it if I'm not getting the throughput I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no for Oracle and according to my research it is also no for DB2. I doubt any others have that feature.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe it's possible in Oracle, or any other DBMS.  However in Oracle you can speed up index creation using options like `PARALLEL` and `NOLOGGING`.

`PARALLEL` allows you to parallelize the processing onto N other CPUS.

`NOLOGGING` forgoes writing to the redo log (which may not be for you).

```
CREATE INDEX some_idx
   ON a_table(col1, col2, col3)
PARALLEL 3
NOLOGGING;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - yes, plenty of ways to help speed up index creation, of which you've mentioned a couple.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you had mutiple single-column indexes, so the following suggestion does not apply here. But I wanted to point it out anyway since it **IS** an example of how to cut down on index creation time in certain cases.

When the table rows are physically sorted in the same order as the index you are building, you may specify the "NOSORT" option in your create index statement. That way Oracle does not have to sort the rows during the index creation (which is a killer when the sort spills to disk).

This is typically useful when you create an empty table (or CTAS), insert the rows in some specific order (enforced by order by), and then directly create an index using the same column order as your order by statement.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed this blog post by [David Aldridge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6742/david-aldridge) from March 2008...

http://oraclesponge.wordpress.com/2008/03/26/how-to-create-multiple-indexes-in-a-single-ddl-statement/